# LINQ get the latest status

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

i got two table in SQL, one is user table and another is status table,i want to get the latest status to display using LINQ.

```
 /// User Table//
userID (Pk) userName telephonenumber 
 1             xx1       xxxxxxxx
 2             xx2       xxxxxxxx2
 3             xx3       xxxxxxxx3
 4             xx4       xxxxxxxx4


statusID(pk)  userID   statusMessage       createdAt    
   1           2        ddddddddx      2012-09-18 13:30:08
   2           4        zzzzddddd      2012-09-18 13:30:10 
   3           1        ssswessss      2012-09-18 16:30:10 
   4           2        ddddddddd      2012-09-18 16:30:15
   5           4        xxxxxweew      2012-09-18 17:30:18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Statuses` is name of your second table, you can use:

```
dbContext.Statuses.OrderBy(a => a.createdAt).Last();
```

You can add some filter (ex. userID) but it is not specified in question.

---

*Update 1, filter by specific userID*

```
dbContext.Statuses.Where(a => a.userID = someID)
                  .OrderBy(a => a.createdAt)
                  .Last();
```

Comment: @thanks,filter by userID, for particular UserID, i want to display, lik the usertable userID which is equal to status table userID

Answer (score 1):

The following should do:

```
result.Max(m => m.createdAt) //To get latest record
result.Min(m => m.createdAt) //To get earlier record
```